# XMLHttpRequest cannot load error when loading local JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, cross-browser

I am trying to load a json file into a table, after doing a lot of research I found solutions on how to do it.

But I am getting the below error on Chrome

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Please suggest how I can avoid this error while loading my json data in chrome.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
 $.getJSON('./files.json')
  .success(function(data) {
     var tr;
     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>");
        $('#table1').append(tr);
    }
})
.error(function(e) { console.error(e); })
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML that I am loading the data into
    
         Name
      Path

Answer (score 2):

The error message spells it out:

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

You can't use `file` URIs here since they aren't listed in the error message.

Install a web server and use `http` instead.